# Show that there is an isomorphism between the 2 modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, finitely-generated

Let $A$ be a P.I.D. Let $K$ be it's field of fractions.

Let $N$ be any $A$-module.

Denote: $N^v := \mathrm{Hom}_A(N, K/A)$.

Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion $A$-module.

Fix any $m\in M$.

Define $\psi_m : M^{v} \rightarrow K/A$ by $\psi_m(\phi) = \phi(m)$, where $\phi\in M^v$.

Define $\Psi : M \rightarrow (M^v)^v$ by $\Psi(m) = \psi_m$.

Show that $\Psi$ is an isomorphism.

I have already shown that $\psi$, $\Psi$ are both homomorphism, thus I believe that to prove the claim we just need to show that $\Psi$ is bijective.

But I'm stuck trying to prove it's injectivity and surjectivity.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you prove it, if $M = A/(a)$ for some $a\in A$?

Comment: that 1 I can, I have some previous results than I can use to arrive at the desired conclusion.

Comment: But what about the general case ? How should I proceed ?

Comment: Use the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PIDs and that the Hom-functor is additive.

Comment: I'm familiar with the structure theorem, (I have used it in one of my attempt), but I'm unfamiliar with the term Hom-functor.

Comment: The Hom-functor being additive just means that for $A$-modules $M_1,M_2,N$ the $A$-linear map ${\rm Hom}_A(M_1\oplus M_2,N) \rightarrow {\rm Hom}_A(M_1,N) \oplus {\rm Hom}_A(M_2,N)$ given by $f\mapsto (f\big|_{M_1}, f\big|_{M_2})$ is an isomorphism.